# Get List of datatable

Tags: jsf

I have the following datatable

```
    <t:dataTable id="data" styleClass="dataTabel"
        headerClass="standardTable_Header" footerClass="standardTable_Header"
        rowClasses="dataTable_Row1,dataTable_Row2"
        columnClasses="standardTable_Column,standardTable_Column,standardTable_Column,standardTable_Column,standardTable_ColumnCentered"
        var="order" value="#{orderList.searchResult}"
        preserveDataModel="true" rowId="#{order.id}"
        sortColumn="#{orderList.sort}" sortAscending="#{orderList.ascending}"
        preserveSort="true">


        <h:column>
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{order.selected}" />
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <t:commandSortHeader columnName="number" arrow="false"
                    immediate="false">
                    <f:facet name="ascending">
                        <t:graphicImage url="/images/arrow_up.jpg" border="0" alt="" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="descending">
                        <t:graphicImage url="/images/arrow_down.jpg" border="0" alt="" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{messages['order_number']}" />
                </t:commandSortHeader>
            </f:facet>
            <t:commandLink action="go_orderForm" immediate="true">
                <h:outputText value="#{order.number}" />
                <t:updateActionListener property="#{orderForm.orderId}"
                    value="#{order.id}" />
            </t:commandLink>
        </h:column>
    </t:dataTable>
```

the value of the datatable will be populated with

```
private List<Order> result = new ArrayList<Order>();
public List<Order> getSearchResult() {
    if ((this.searchPattern != null) && (this.searchPattern.length() > 0)) {
        this.result = EJBFactory.getOrderManager().searhOrderByNumber(
                this.searchPattern);
    } else {
        this.result = this.getCurrentOrders();
    }

    return this.result;
}
```

When I check a Checkbox of a row, the property `order.selected` will be set correctly.
There is also a commandLink on the page:

```
    <h:commandLink action="#{orderList.createBatchOrder}">
        <h:outputText value="#{messages['order_new_batch']}" />
    </h:commandLink>
```

The method `orderList.createBatchOrder()` will be executed, when I click on it. 
But the property `result` (which will be set in the method `getSearchResult()`) will be empty in `createBatchOrder()`.

How can I get the row-objects in the method `createBatchOrder()`?

Comment: In the  <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{order.selected}" /> you can add ajax and update value in backing bean with the row index using ajax.

Comment: Maybe the scope of the bean is wrong for your use case. Please try to provide a [mcve]

Comment: `t:datatable` is? Tomahawk?